# custom XMPP messages with Strophe.js

Tags: javascript, xmpp, strophe

How can I send custom messages with **XMPP** using the **[Strophe JS](http://strophe.im/strophejs/)** library?

I know that using `$msg(    ... );` I can create a chat message element and `connection.send(m);` send it through XMPP connection.

I need a way to send messages not for chat but for "command" (or other purpose).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Strophe.js you can simply do:

```
function sendCustomMessage(to, from, body, field1, field2) {
    var m = $msg({to: to, from: from, type: 'chat'}).c("body").t(body);     
   // custom data
   m.up().c("data", {xmlns: 'my-custom-data-ns', field1: field1, field2: field2});
   connection.send(m);
}
```

Comment: We don't want to use $msg.

Comment: @beaver how to i add namespace like this `<message  cli:subject="TEXT MESSAGE"></message>`

Comment: @beaver can you give some more detail about this file Strophe.js where it is located and where i have to define this function?

Answer (score 4):

In XMPP you can add custom payload in the XML stanza, for example:

```
<message id="xyz" type="chat" to="tojid@com" from="fromjid@com">
    <body>....</body>
    <data xmlns='mycustom-data-ns'
      myField1="bye" myField2="data" />
</message>
```

Check on Strophe.js docs how to create that msg.

Comment: Don't know how to do that with Strope.js... :(